# Getting an error using to_datetime function in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like the below. Im trying to convert this to datetime using to_datetime function

Example: `2020-03-13 08-PM`

Im getting error while using below code

```
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'],format = "%Y-%m-%d %I-%p")
```

Note:df2 contains datasets similar to the example given above

Comment: You may have irregularities in the data. try passing `errors='coerce'` to `to_datetime`

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: Thanks Quang. This helps. Could you please explain about that argument as I'm a beginner in pandas